# How does mocking with Mocha actually allow you to test the logic in a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-mocha

I started out learning how to mock things because using Factory Girl just isn't very practical for projects with 1000+ tests. I can't be hitting the database for every test, especially if I hope to do any sort of automated continuous integration.

My Test:

```
    it "should return an URL with the desired security protocol" do
        p = Proposal.new
        p.expects(:status).returns(Proposal::PUBLISHED) #this should be invoked by public_url?
        p.expects(:public_url).returns("https://something")
        p.expects(:public_url).with(true).returns("https://something")
        p.expects(:public_url).with(false).returns("http://something")
        assert p.public_url.index("https") != nil
        assert p.public_url(true).index("https") != nil
        assert p.public_url(false).index("https") == nil
    end
```

The method for the above test:

```
def public_url(https = true)
    url = ""
    if self.published?
        # attepmt to find sluggable id
        id = sluggable_id
        url = (https ? "#{ENV['SSL_PROTOCOL']}://" : "http://") + 
            self.account.full_domain + "/view/" + id.to_s
    end

    return url
end 

def published?
    return self.status > UNPUBLISHED
end
```

But this is what I get when I run the test:

```
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Proposal:0x7fbd07e82a30>.status(any_parameters)
```

Shouldn't the call to `public_url` invoke `status()`?

If not, then if I have to call `p.status` myself, doesn't that mean that `p.public_url()` is completetly ignoring the logic I have written, and strictly following what I have defined in `expects`?
How does that help with unit testing?
Maybe I don't understand the purpose of mocking.

---

UPDATE:

I changed my test to this, as per @Philip's suggestion, removing the need for any ActiveRecord shenanigans:

```
    it "should return an URL with the desired security protocol" do
        p = Proposal.new
        p.expects(:id).returns(1)
        p.expects(:status).returns(Proposal::PUBLISHED)
        p.expects(:account).returns(Account.new.stubs(:localhost))

        assert p.public_url.starts_with("https")
        assert p.public_url(true).starts_with("https")
        assert !p.public_url(false).starts_with("https")
    end
```

I guess now my question is, how do I stub out an account, using a fixture (that I have named `localhost`?). I get an error: `undefined method 'full_domain' for Mocha::Expectation:` but my fixture is defined as follows:

```
localhost:
  id: 1
  name: My first account
  full_domain: test.domain.vhost
```

I set up fixtures such that I could have the very basics of commonly accessed models for easy use throughout all of my tests. The Standard Model/Relationship for EVERY test (if I were do the testing by hand/with factory girl with no mocking, would require this:
`Account`, `Subscription` (has `Account`, `SubscriptionPlan`), `SubscriptionPlan`, `User` (belongs to `Account`), `AccountProperties` (has `Account`), and then the actual Object I'm testing on, which belongs to an `Account` and a `User` on that `Account`, which is a bit much for every test. haha

---

UPDATE 2:

Got it working:

```
it "should return an URL with the desired security protocol" do
            p = Proposal.new({:status => Proposal::PUBLISHED})
            p.expects(:id).returns(1)
            p.expects(:account).returns(accounts(:localhost)).times(3)

            assert p.public_url.starts_with?("https")
            assert p.public_url(true).starts_with?("https")
            assert !p.public_url(false).starts_with?("https")
        end
```

turns out, you access fixtures like, `accounts` or `users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of it is that your three `p.expects(:public_url)...` lines are stubbing out that method and returning the values you've told it to return.  So once you've done that you're method body is never being called... the stub has taken over.  Hence... since you told it to expect a call to `status` as well, that is never going to happen.

Looking at your code... I think what you want to stub out is `self.account.full_domain` and possibly `id.to_s` in this line:

```
url = (https ? "#{ENV['SSL_PROTOCOL']}://" : "http://") + 
            self.account.full_domain + "/view/" + id.to_s
```

That will skip any AR relation stuff, but still exercise the rest of the conditions in your method.

Also..  I would change your assertions.  The below will also match a non secure url like "http://https.com/blahblah" which isn't what you really want.  The other ones could also pass, but for invalid reasons as well.

```
assert p.public_url(true).index("https") != nil
```

So maybe something like:

```
assert p.public_url(true).starts_with("https://") true
```

Or, take the result and parse it using URI and then test the scheme directly (probably overkill thought)

Comment: I updated my question with my new findings. We /may/ be closer? haha. idk. thanks for the starts_with tip!